# Posts ordering by publish date using WP_Query exclude Year

Tags: wordpress

Need ordering posts by publish date and order posts by DAY. 
Now if use default ordering:

```
            $args = array (
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'monthnum'  => '1',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order'   => 'ASC',                    
                'posts_per_page' => '-1'
            );
```

We have post ordered by Year like:

21.01.**2016**

03.01.**2017**

16.01.**2018**

....

But need order only by Day:

**03**.01.2017

**16**.01.2018

**21**.01.2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`posts_orderby`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) to filter the `ORDER BY` clause.

This would go the theme `functions.php` file:

```
function posts_orderby_day( $sql, $query ) {
    if ( 'day' === $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $order = $query->get( 'order' );
        $sql = "DAY( {$wpdb->posts}.post_date ) $order";
    }
    return $sql;
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby_day', 10, 2 );
```

And then in your `$args`, set the `orderby` to `day`:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'monthnum'       => '1',
    'orderby'        => 'day', // set to "day"
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!